# How to integrate Intellij and Databricks, like when using the jdwp with a regular Spark cluster?

Tags: apache-spark, databricks, jdwp, scala-spark

I have been looking online for awhile, but have found nothing, thus this question. I would like to be able to debug my Apache Spark code (written in Scala) remotely on Databricks, similar to the way it can be done on regular Spark clusters using the Java Debug Wire Protocol (or jdwp). Is this possible at all? Can it, perhaps, be done using the Databrick Labs dbx tool? Or just by using a host and port number (and, possibly as well, a Databricks token) with said jdwp?

Any response will be greatly aprreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could use databricks connect setup to configure host and token on your local and can debug the code.

Comment: @NikunjKakadiya Kakadiya Thanks! I had forgotten that databricks connect existed! The only thing I do not like is that its use seems to be discouraged by Databricks itself. Do you know if the same feature (i.e., remote debugging) can be achieved through dbx?

Comment: It should work with dbx also. You can check out databricks official documentation for the same. If your purpose is just debugging databricks connect should also work.